# DataInputStream sometimes reads NaN instead of a float

Tags: java, android

Bit of a Java newb. Writing an STL file viewer. I'm reading floats from a binary file using a DataInputStream but randomly getting NaN on some values. The file, when opened on a PC in STL file readers seems to be intact, but the NaN values I'm getting mean quite a few of the facets in the file are corrupted. What circumstances could lead to a DataInputStream returning NaN?

My code seems to work fine, it is just these random NaNs which are driving me crazy. Here's a truncated version of the reading code - all pretty straightforward I think. Any help is much appreciated:

```
public static int GetFacetBinary(DataInputStream in, ArrayList al, ArrayList aln) {

        <snip>

        // read 1st vertex
        fxr = in.readFloat();
        f1x = swap(fxr);
        al.add(f1x);
        if (fminx > f1x) fminx = f1x;
        if (fmaxx < f1x) fmaxx = f1x;

        fyr = in.readFloat();
        f1y = swap(fyr);
        al.add(f1y);
        if (fminy > f1y) fminy = f1y;
        if (fmaxy < f1y) fmaxy = f1y;

        fzr = in.readFloat();
        f1z = swap(fzr);
        al.add(f1z);
        if (fminz > f1z) fminz = f1z;
        if (fmaxz < f1z) fmaxz = f1z;

        iVertCount++;
                    <snip>
```

Edit: Found a workaround but still no idea why readFloat occasionally returns NaN. I'd still be interested in an answer to that question. Now I read four bytes, bitshift them, convert that to a float and it works perfectly:

```
in.readFully(fourbytes);
v1  = ((fourbytes[3]&0xff) << 24) | ((fourbytes[2]&0xff) << 16) | 
      ((fourbytes[1]&0xff) << 8) | ((fourbytes[0]&0xff) << 0);
f1x = Float.intBitsToFloat(v1);
```

And I was doing the shift later anyway to convert endianness, which is now not needed, so I guess it isn't a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking I think NaN stands for "Not a Number" hence reading from the STL file might work flawlessly but parsing the value might fail due to numerous reasons.

Spontaneously I think you're trying to parse an empty string from the file (by the `in.readFloat()` lines), but it could be anything else that is not possible to parse to a float (like "abc" or maybe even "1,3" - as opposed to "1.3").

I don't know what an "STL file" is or how it's built, but is there any guarantee that the values you're reading are always possible to parse as float values?

Comment: Yes, NaN is not a number. I'm reading a binary file and the value goes straight into a float so no parsing required. All the other values are read perfectly, just a few are NaN. The STL file describes a mesh of triangles, but that isn't all that relevant since the file can be successfully read by other software. I'm just in need of tips why DataInputStream might give me a NaN instead of a valid float.

Comment: Yes if it's a binary file then it's fair to assume that there is no "string-to-float" parsing :-) Unfortunately I don't have any further ideas on what might cause the error :-(

Answer (score 0):

DataInputStream uses Float.intBitsToFloat(bytes) to convert number to float. Documentation for it states:

> If the argument is any value in the range 0x7f800001 through
>   0x7fffffff or in the range 0xff800001 through 0xffffffff, the result
>   is a NaN.

So, possibly you're reading not valid float number.

Comment: Sweet. Do you know if it would make a difference if one would try to read it as a double instead and then cast the double to float (if necessary at all)?

Comment: The numbers are pretty small, eg in a couple of files which fail, one set is -0.5 nto +0.5 and the other about +0.25 to +300.0 so way within float bounds. as dbm says though I'll do a quick test of reading a double and casting that to a float.

Comment: Doh, of course I can't read doubles because only floats are stored in the file. I guess I can read four byes and derive the float from that?

Comment: At least You can run it in debug and see what are You reading, possibly You could miss to read some value and so lost real offset of float value. He can not read it as double value, because it's a binary format and he must read exactly 4 bytes for it